# Need help identifying AC power connector

Tags: power, connector

I picked up this (rather unique?) Tektronix spot welder at a sale a couple weeks ago. I haven't figured out whether it needs 120V or 220V service, and it didn't come with a power cord. The power should come through this male socket in the photograph.

[image]
[image]

Let me know if further details are needed. Thanks!
Edits: 
- added front panel image. M

Comment: Looks nonstandard. Any other details available?  (e.g. model number)

Comment: I can't find anything that's positively the model number, just serial number 646. Tektronix headquarters is in my area (Portland, OR) and I imagine this was used as a part of their prototyping labs (maybe production?) back in the mid-20th century. I'll try to get measurements of the connector later tonight.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a variant of NEMA L-series TwistLock. The center hole is obscure. [image]

[image]

EDIT: closest one so far:
30 A 208Y/120 V L21-30 with two phases omitted. 
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the lead! The spot welder only has two pins, but maybe a 4-hole female connect works with it. I'll research these.

Comment: @JamesPalmer You’re welcome! Look at NEMA L21-30. One of these three phase variants with only one phase in use by your connector?

Comment: Sounds good. I'll measure the spot welder connector tonight and see if it matches the NEMA L21-30 specs.

Comment: @JamesPalmer Any success?

Comment: Thanks for following up. I measured a (roughly) 0.6" diameter at the pins. That seems to be too small for NEMA L21-30, which from eyeballing the drawing here has  ~25mm has close to 1" diameter at the pins. http://www.internationalconfig.com/documents/L2130-C.pdf

Comment: I did however see that "p1660" is on the connecter, and following on that lead it may in fact be an ML-2R spec connector.

Answer (score 1):

After following up on winny's direction, it seems that I should be looking for an ML-2R connector.

[image]

Comment: Correct.  Takes me back to the early 70's, building a TV station.  Lotsa Tek gear.